# Is it possible to override a plugin class that is using if( ! class_exist('classname') )?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is something like overriding a plugin class when there is `if( ! class_exists('classname') )` possible?

I know this can be done by themes with functions so you can override their function but i would like to know if this can be done with plugins as well.

Comment: Can you expand on what it is you are trying to accomplish for an end result

Comment: @RyanH Hi Ryan, i already found out how to override the class, but the end result would be off topic for this question, so i posted a new question and i have it linked below. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Since i already found out the solution my goal eventually with this, is off topic so i will ask another question relative to that. For anyone that has the same question as i did here's how i solved it:

When a plugin has `if( ! class_exists('classname') )` copy the class inside the if to your theme's or childtheme's functions.php.

I don't know if this is the proper way but it works.

Edit: Link to where i am going with this [Acf Create Terms popup save term custom field values when clicking add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489411/acf-create-terms-popup-save-term-custom-field-values-when-clicking-add)